# Pandas compare two cells (Not column)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to compare two cells in pandas dataframe:

```
if df['col1'][0] < df['col2'][0]:
      ...
```

The cells that need to be compared are in the same row, but different columns, and I just need to compare the two specific cells. However I google, everything is about compare whole columns.

[image: Error]

The image above show that when I run it, it stuck there for so long, but when I remove the IF statement, it works smoothly.
[image: My Actual codes]

Can anyone tell me on how should I do it? thanks[image: The dataframe look like]

I hope the IF statement will pass if two cells with column names are compared

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve

Comment: @BERA I want to compare the 'pax' if it exceeds 'max pax' or not, if exceed then need to stop, but it takes long time if I put this comparison in my code

Comment: Try numpy where

Comment: @BERA can you type out the code of modification on this sample code so I can know how should I write it, as I try at my end it fail...
Btw I have many actions if the result is true

Comment: Please provide source code with minimum input data which reproduces the problem and show us what your expected output should look like.

Comment: provide a minimal example of the data, explain the logic you want to achieve, provide the matching expected output

Comment: df.assign(column=lambda x: (np.where(x["first_col"] > x["compare"],when True,when False)
or something like .query("firstcol > compare_to_col")
Is a far better way

Comment: Hi let me ask another way round, is there any method to use IF statement to compare two different cells in pandas dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to perform this, but since you really haven't established the purpose of what function will be performed for any or all dataframe rows where "col1" is less than "col2", you might just use the "loc" function for dataframes to extract a subset dataframe to work with.  Following is a snippet of code that illustrates that possible route.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 44], [222, 48], [1024,449], [433, 788]], columns=['col1', 'col2'])

print(df)

df2 = df.loc[df['col1'] < df['col2']]

print(df2)
```

Here is the result at the terminal when running that snippet.

```
@Una:~/Python_Programs/CompareColumns$ python3 CompareColumns.py 
   col1  col2
0     1    44
1   222    48
2  1024   449
3   433   788
   col1  col2
0     1    44
3   433   788
```

As noted, that is just one way you might address what you are trying to accomplish in your column comparison.

Give that a try.